# Create a separate landing page in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

is it possible to create a standalone landing page beside of complete website in Wordpress for the purpose of google ads

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Just save is at a HTML (or even PHP file). As long as you don't load wp-blog-header.php file in your code, it will be independent from your WordPress installation.